# Headers width in memoir class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, memoir

I want to extend the length of the headers using the margin space, in `memoir` class. For this I use

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}

\makepagestyle{test}
\makerunningwidth{test}{\headwidth}
\makeoddhead{test}{Left}{Center}{Right}
\pagestyle{test}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

However, the left side of the margin was also extended
[image]

Is there any way to extend the header only to the right? That is, so that "Left" is aligned with the text block.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to make the header asymmetric, but you could add some horizontal space to the left part to make it align with the left margin.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\leftspace}
\setlength{\leftspace}{\dimexpr\parindent+2\marginparsep\relax}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}

\makepagestyle{test}
\makerunningwidth{test}{\headwidth}
\makeoddhead{test}{\hspace*{\leftspace}Left}{Center}{Right}
\pagestyle{test}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Comment: In my header and yours the word "Right" seems to be in the same position. So, I should make `\headwith` bigger to make it appear to be the right size, right?

Comment: I’m not really sure what you mean. I assumed you were happy with the position of the right side. Have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Sorry, is not something really important and, as you said, I'm happy with your result